# What is the pronunciation of "Un étudiant actif étranger"?

Tags: liaisons

I have some questions with regard to the liaison between a noun and its first adjective, as well as the subsequent adjectives. I know that in the phrase "des langue**s** étrangères", the "s" makes liaison as /z/. However, I don't know if I should make a liaison for "un étudiant actif étranger".

Should it be

> Eu-né-tu-dian-**t**ac-ti-**v**é-tran-gé ?

or should it be

> Eu-né-tu-dia-**n**ac-ti-**f**é-tran-gé ?

Moreover, how about "un étudiant curieu**x** étranger"?

Comment: By the way, there's never a case of liaison that turns "*actif*" into "*active*" afaik.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat Thanks for the heads-up. I was affected by the liaison for "neuf heures".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no liaison between *étudiant* and *actif*, and neither between *actif* and *étranger* (where do you get that from?). There's always a liaison after *un* though.

So it's:

> Un-né-tu-dian-ac-tif-é-tran-gé

And I don't think there's ever a liaison after *curieux*.

---

Rule of thumb of the comments, condensed:

**Generally**, in a sentence with *[article]+[noun]+[adjective]*, there's a liaison on the noun, but not on the adjective after the noun.

Ex:

> Des **z**histoires ( )étranges

Whereas in *[article]+[adjective]+[noun]*, there is a liaison both on the adjective and on the noun.

> Des **z**étranges **z**histoires

Of course, this applies only if the words can have a liaison. There's no liaison in "*Un grand bûcheron*" for example.

Comment: Because "langues étrangères" needs liaison, I thought maybe "étudiant actif" needs liaison as well. Does it mean only plural nouns need a liaison?

Comment: @Jimmy Actually, liaisons are a little more complicated than that. It depends more on habits than on rules as to what gets a liaison and what doesn't. (For example, a lot of people say "langues étrangères" with a liaison but it's not an obligation).

Comment: @Jimmy As a rule of thumb, most liaison happen on **nouns**, and rarely on **adjectives**. Ex: "*Des **z**immeubles*", "*Des grands **z**immeubles*", but "*Des **z**immeubles **i**mmenses*" (no liaison on "immense"). "*Langues étrangères*" is actually kind of an exception.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Comment: There is certainly a liaison after *curieux* in some cases, with a "z" sound. Try to pronounce "de curieux échafaudages" for example (yes, I can see construction work outside my office window).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yeah, as far as I know, in the construction [article] + [adjective] + [noun], both the adjective and the verb have a liaison. Ex: "*Des **z**étranges **z**histoires*" (vs "*Des **z**histoires ( )étranges*")

Comment: @TeleportingGoat when inverting noun and adjective, you would rather replace "des" by "de" : de curieux amis, de tristes journées. When adjective starts with a vowel, you would even elude the "e": "d'ambitieux amis" , "d'agréables journées". But this is a completely different question...

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which one is the noun and which one is the adjective, the liaison might be done or not:

> *Un curieux (z) étranger*: A curious foreigner (*curieux* is an adjective, *étranger* is a noun. Liaison possible but optional)
>
> *Un curieux étranger*: A foreign onlooker (*curieux* is a noun, *étranger* is an adjective. Forbidden liaison because *curieux* is singular)

*Un étudiant curieux étranger* and *étudiant actif étranger* are not very idiomatic. We'd rather say either:

> *Un étudiant étranger curieux* / *Un étudiant étranger actif*

or

> *Un curieux étudiant étranger*.

Comment: So I guess there's no liaison for "un cours étranger" because the "cours" here is singular, but for "des cours étrangers", there is liaison since "cours" is plural?

Comment: Yes, the *liaison* is forbidden in the first case and optional in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a liaison after curieux. The same as "Un heureux événement" that is pronounced "heureuZévénement"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/22619)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).